# find out the volume of solid removed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

i have sphere that has an equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ a cylindrical hole $x^2+(y-1/2)^2$=$1/4$ is cut through it . find the volume of the portion cut. i don't know what to do, i was thinking of using cavalieri's principle , and integrate with respect to $dz$ but i could not imagine the equation of sheets that would be formed . i guess we can proceed with polar , but i don't know how? please help

Comment: A tricky calculus I problem for sure.

Comment: You could integrate a triple integral in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: i dont know how to go about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate in yucky cartesian coordinates you would do for the sphere:

$$V_\textrm{sphere} =\int_{-1}^1dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}}dz = 8*\int_0^1dx\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}}dz$$

(to see this worked out in some detail see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIf78H50iNc)

To get the missing cylinder, you need to integrate over the region of the cylinder, Same $z$ bounds, but just integrate $x$ and $y$ over the cylindrical region given by your equation.

viz. $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}dx\int_{(1/2) -\sqrt{1/4-x^2}}^{(1/2) +\sqrt{1/4-x^2}}dy\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}}dz $$

Comment: but the problem is that though cylinder is drilled , the part that is drilled is not a cylinder right?

Comment: No it is, at least, the sides are. The top and bottom are bounded by the sphere so the $z$ integral is just like the one above. The $x$ and $y$ integrals go over the region of the cylinder.

Comment: I added the cylinder part. Basically you just solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ from your equation that defines the cylinder. Also $x$ goes from $-r$ to $r$ where $r$ is the radius of the cylinder.

Comment: oh i get it, that was nice , although if i had changed cylinder into a sphere of radius of 1/2 centred at (0,1/2,0) both the integrals would still remain the same right ?

Comment: No because the $z$ limits would change to be $\pm \sqrt{(1/4)-y^2-z^2}$ as it is you integrate $z$ up to the unit sphere.

Comment: k sorry to disturb you , but in the second equation i am still not sure why did you set the limits as $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and  $-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

Comment: i understood the change of limits in the sphere as  mentioned in comments , but not the part in the original equation

Comment: The $z$ integral limits come from your first equation (solve for $z$) of the sphere. Your removed cylinder is bounded by the sphere in the $z$ direction so you use that equation. For $x$ and $y$ you use the other equation since that bounds those directions. If you have further comments we can chat about it later.

Comment: no thats it , thank you :)